# MapQuickItem loaded with Loader does not display

Tags: qt, qml

I am building a mapping program that eventually wants to display a different item on the map based on a value within the model.  To facilitate this, I'm using `Loader` in my `MapItemView` delegate.

Unfortunately, when I tested this, the `Loader` method displayed nothing.

**MapItemDelegate.qml**

```
MapQuickItem {
    id: waypoint
    anchorPoint.x: image.width/2
    anchorPoint.y: image.height/2
    coordinate: task.waypoint //task extends QObject with members taskname and waypoint
    
    sourceItem: Grid: {
        columns: 1
        rows:2
        horizontalItemAlignment: Grid.AlignHCenter
        Image {
            id: image
            source: "Waypoint.png"
            height: 32
            width: 32
        }
        Text {
            id: text
            text: task.taskname
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
MapItemView {
    id: taskview
    model: tasklistmodel //Extends AbstractListModel to contain task objects
    delegate: Component {
        //Desired method, fails to display.
        Loader {
            source:"MapItemDelegate.qml"
            // Will eventually be:
            // source: task.typename+"MapItemDelegate.qml" to facilitate several types.
        }

        //Control method.  Works fine, but does not meet my requirements.
        MapItemDelegate {
            //Nothing further needed.
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get `MapItemView` to actually display `MapQuickItems` loaded with `Loader`?  Is there another method of dynamically loading delegates for display?

Comment: What is the goal of using `Loader` here? why not just `delegate: MapItemDelegate {}`? And what's the point in using both `Loader` and `MapItemDelegate` in the delegate? Why not  to use `Column` or `ColumnLayout` instead of `Grid` with single column? Are you sure that your model provides data?

Comment: As shown in the commented `Will eventually be` section, I have a `typename` field in my model and want to change my delegate based upon it, which is a normal use case for `Loader`.  `MapItemDelegate`, while it works for a single type of delegate, does not meet my requirements for a different delegate for each `typename`.  I used both in the example for brevity, but would not in real life.  I have confirmed the model contains data with other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, using a `Loader` within a delegate of `MapItemView` is not possible, as the API demands the `Component` contain a single mapping object.  While `Loader` did load a mapping object, it is not in itself a mapping object, which caused the object to fail to display.

What I ended up doing is implementing a custom `QSortFilterProxyModel` that overrides `filterAcceptsRow` to filter `tasklistmodel` to match the `task.typename` property, then editing my `MapItemView` as follows:

```
MapItemView {
    id:taskview
    model: TaskListFilterModel { // custom extension of QSortFilterProxyModel
        acceptType:"dothisthingtype"
        sourceModel: tasklistmodel
    }
    delegate:MapItemDelegate {
    }
}
```

With that, I can add a `MapItemView` for each type of task I plan to add in the future.  While it's far less elegant and way more work than I had hoped to achieve with `Loader`, it does at least meet my requirements.